# How To Get Value of the Control on Postback which is Assigned by jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery

I assigned a value to a jQuery hidden field and I want to pass the value to a button click event through postback:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("[id$=_imgsetreminder]").click(function() {
    $("[id$=hiddReminderTicketId]").val(100);
    return false;
});
```

However, in my C# code-behind, the value of s is null:

```
 string s = hiddReminderTicketId.value();
```

Comment: witch version of .net are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess jQuery couldn't find the controls with the IDs that you specified.
If you are using .NET 4.0 set the ClientIDMode to "static" in the control's markup.
Otherwise try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[id$=<%= _imgsetreminder.ClientID %>]").click(function() {
        $("[id$=<%= hiddReminderTicketId.ClientID %>]").val(100);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: i have set the value successfully, but the problem is i want the value to insert database, while i am trying to find the value on code behind it gives null value

Comment: just saying: `hiddReminderTicketId.value();` is not correct in C#, it should be `hiddReminderTicketId.Value;`
Can you make sure that you are not overriding the value of the HiddenField in Page_PreInit, Page_Init, Page_Load ?